# How to smoothly scroll a specified amount when holding down a directional key

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, scroll

I am creating a timeEditor with vue3.
Currently it works smoothly when scrolling with the wheel. It also works when scrolling by pressing the keyboard one by one. However, if I hold down the keyboard, it works once, but after that it doesn't move as much as I specify, and the scroll moves a little bit.
If I remove the scroll-behavior: smooth; attribute in the css, it works smoothly when scrolling with the wheel and jerky when scrolling with the keyboard.
I want it to scroll smoothly even when I scroll by holding down a keyboard arrow without using JQuery.

```css
.cssDivTimeScroll {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;

    -ms-overflow-style: none !important;
}
.cssDivTimeScroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none !important;
}
#divScrolla,
#divScrollb {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}
.scroll-item {
    scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Vue 3 Time Scroll</title>
  <!-- Include Vue.js -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.0.11"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <div
      id="divScrolla"
      class="text-center cssDivTimeScroll"
      style="
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        white-space: nowrap;
        height: 100px;
        font-size: 4em;
      "
      tabindex="0"
      @keydown="handleKeyDown"
    >
      <div v-for="item in hours" :id="`hour${item}`" class="scroll-item" style="height: 100px">
        {{ item }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    const hours = Array.from({ length: 24 }, (_, index) => index.toString().padStart(2, '0'));

    function handleKeyDown(event) {
      if (event.key === 'ArrowDown') {
        event.preventDefault();
        scrollNext(event.target);
      } else if (event.key === 'ArrowUp') {
        event.preventDefault();
        scrollPrevious(event.target);
      }
    }

    function scrollNext(el) {
      el.scrollBy(0, 100);
    }

    function scrollPrevious(el) {
      el.scrollBy(0, -100);
    }

    const app = Vue.createApp({
      data() {
        return {
          hours: hours,
        };
      },
      methods: {
        handleKeyDown(event) {
          if (event.key === 'ArrowDown') {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.scrollNext(event.target);
          } else if (event.key === 'ArrowUp') {
            event.preventDefault();
            this.scrollPrevious(event.target);
          }
        },
        scrollNext(el) {
          el.scrollBy(0, 100);
        },
        scrollPrevious(el) {
          el.scrollBy(0, -100);
        },
      },
    });

    app.mount('#app');
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```